# What does the type in the formatting types syntax do?

Tags: formatting, rust

What does the ‘type’ in the formatting types [syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#syntax) of `format!` do?

Of this, that is:

> `[[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision][type]`

The rest appears to be well documented, but that particular one seems to have some information left out. Under its explanation it says:

> `type := identifier | ''`

But what on Earth is it used for?

### Edits

#### 1.

Someone suggested that they be for [named parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#named-parameters), and that feels reasonable to assume. However, should the following code not work had that been the case?

```
println!("{:.2test}", test=32.432);
```

This generates me a rather depressing error:

> ```
> error: unknown format trait `test`
>   --> src\main.rs:12:29
>    |
> 12 |    println!("{:.2test}", test=32.432);
>    |                               ^^^^^^
> ```

Comment: Please disregard my previous replies. That was a mistake. It is actually  for [formatting traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits)

Comment: Absolutely no problem. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What must be noted here is that the syntax above is for `format_spec`, which always follows a colon.

> `format := '{' [ argument ] [ ':' format_spec ] '}'`
>
> `format_spec := [[fill]align][sign]['#']['0'][width]['.' precision][type]`

With that in mind, the `type` part is used to specify [formatting traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits), which are documented as thus:

> When requesting that an argument be formatted with a particular type, you are actually requesting that an argument ascribes to a particular trait. This allows multiple actual types to be formatted via `{:x}` (like i8 as well as isize).
>
> [...]
>
> If no format is specified (as in {} or {:6}), then the format trait used is the Display trait.

Here's an example ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5e1a3bc4232f167dc7828d057218b413&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
println!("{:b}", 31); // prints 11111
println!("{:08b}", 31); // prints 00011111
```

Type formatting works for any data type that implements the corresponding formatting type, such as [`Binary`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Binary.html) or [`LowerHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html).

---

At first I guessed it would be named parameters, but those actually go before the colon. Just for the record, this also works ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0fa4e4f3e9c28a89b189f3de31739fb1&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
format!("{a:08b}", a = 31)
```